# How can i put data in the thinker entry from a loop (Python)

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, set

How can i use set() method or there is method to update data in widget. I get this error : AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'set'

my example code:

```
from tkinter import *

Entradas = []

def convertir():
    for entrada in Entradas:
        print(float(entrada.get())/1024)
    for entrada in Entradas:
        entrada.set((float(entrada.get())/1024))


app= Tk()
app.resizable(0,0)

for i in range(3):
    etiqueta = Label(app, text = "Numero " + str(i + 1) + " : ")
    etiqueta.grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = "w", padx = 5, pady = 5)

for i in range(3):
    Numero = Entry(app, font = "Arial 8 bold")
    Numero.grid(row = i, column = 1 , padx = 5, pady = 5)
    Numero.config(justify="left", disabledforeground="white")
    Entradas.append(Numero)

Button(app, text="Convertir", command=convertir,font = "Arial 10 bold").grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

app.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: That's because Entry widgets don't have the attribute `set()` as your track back has stated.

Comment: Your first step should be to read the documentation for the Entry widget. All of its methods are documented.

Comment: thanks, is to be able to use a stringvar in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `insert()` not `set()`

For entry fields you need specify the location as to where to insert the text and the text itself.

So instead of:

```
entrada.set((float(entrada.get())/1024))
```

Do this:

```
entrada.insert(0, (float(entrada.get())/1024))
```

Now if you want to make sure the entry field is cleared before your add text to it then you need to do this:

```
entrada.delete(0, "end")
entrada.insert(0, (float(entrada.get())/1024))
```

Comment: excellent, made some changes and worked, thank you for sharing your knowledge and experience.